# Does the user have to be logged in to the machine for C# SendKeys.Send() to work?

Tags: c#, user-interface, automation, sendkeys

Does the user have to be always logged in to the PC for SendKeys.Send() to work? Can the user running that particular application have the machine in locked state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the SendKeys.Send(string keys) sends keystrokes to the active application. when the user is not logged, there is not active application. the locked state is not considered as an active application.
so no, the SendKeys won't work for you.

Comment: thnx for confirming :(

Comment: Do you know of a way to send a key combination (string) while the user is in locked state?